# Labels on both sides of a HSlider or VSlider control

Tags: apache-flex, slider

Is there some way to have labels on both sides of a VSlider control?

I need this to show meters on one side and feet on the other side....

- Sami

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its possible unless you extend those existing controls.